# PHP if() Statement Issue

Tags: php, if-statement

Here is an image of my problem, I can't post images yet..
http://rune-shadows.com/hiscores/img.PNG
http://rune-shadows.com/hiscores/img1.PNG

Why is my if statement giving Nic5 a moderator icon, when his playerRights are 0?

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($temp_score!=$row['0'])
    $rank++;
    $pr = $row['playerRights'];
    echo '<tr>
        <td>'.($rank).'</td>';
        if ($pr = 1) {
            echo '<td><img src ="img/mod.gif">&nbsp;<a href="personal.php?name='. htmlspecialchars($row['username']) .'">'. htmlspecialchars($row['username']) .'</a></td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td><a href="personal.php?name='. htmlspecialchars($row['username']) .'">'. htmlspecialchars($row['username']) .'</a></td>';
        }

        echo '
            <td>'.number_format($row['LVL']).'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($row['XP']).'</td>
        </tr>';
     $count++;
  }
```

Comment: `=` is the **assignment operator**, `==` is for comparison.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is one of the 999 rookie mistakes that don't require yet another dedicated question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a comparison:

```
if ($pr === 1) {
...    
}
```

`$pr = 1` is always true, since you're setting a variable, not comparing it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of line:

```
  if ($pr = 1)
```

You should have:

```
  if ($pr == 1)
```

You should use == instead of = operator.

In PHP == is for equality and = is for assignment.
Now you can understand why is expression "($pr = 1)" always true.

[PHP operator documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($pr = 1) {
```

should be

```
if ($pr === 1) {
```

or at least

```
if ($pr == 1) {
```

Comment: Upvoted as it shouldn't be a -1.

Comment: Although it's a duplicate, here's a +1 for the `===` :)

Comment: so much peace on SO <3